# PHP paging not working

Tags: php

So basically i created a webpage with url:

```
http://localhost/bbe/alumni/showthread.php?t=19
$limit = 8;
$offset = (isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] - 1 : 0) * $limit;
```

Then put a comment section (with paging) but my codes for paging is not working

```
<?php
        $total = $dbcon->query("SELECT count(*) FROM comment") or die(mysqli_error());
        $fetch = $total->fetch_assoc();


        for($x = 0; $x < $fetch["count(*)"] / $limit ; $x ++)
        {
          $page = $x + 1;
          if((isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1) == $page) $page = "<b>".$page."</b>";
          echo '<a href="showthread.php?t='.$id.'?page='.($x + 1).'" class="label label-danger">'.$page.'</a>&nbsp;';
        }
      ?>
```

after 8 comments there is the page number but when i clicked the link for page 2 nothing happens except for the url is changed to:

```
http://localhost/bbe/alumni/showthread.php?t=19?page=2
```

and also if i clicked back to page 1 the url changed to

```
http://localhost/bbe/alumni/showthread.php?t=19?page=2?page=1
```

and so on.. why does the link in my paging doesn't work? sorry im new in php and still learning online

Comment: additional request variables need to be separated by `&`, not `?`, so the url should become `http://localhost/bbe/alumni/showthread.php?t=19&page=2`. Also, look into limiting your query result in stead of paging in PHP, this will become very slow as the amount of data increases

Comment: @Pevara paging now works because i separated request variables by ampersand. but how will i limit my query result? im still confused about what it really mean. codes in comment() goes like this:
`"SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit"`

Comment: my mistake, I did not read your code carefully and assumed you where fetching the actual comments, while it seems you are just using the total count to build the pager links. If this works for you the code is fine, no need to limit the query results.

Comment: @ronstoppable your problem is the links right ? can you explain for me please what's the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @MehdiBounya yes, my problem was the link. but its now solved. thanks to Pevara. i didnt know that different request variables needs to be separated by `&` and not `?`

Comment: @Pevara you may want to post your comment as an answer

Comment: I followed your advise @MehdiBounya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already commented, additional request variables need to be separated by `&`, not `?`. So the url should become `http://localhost/bbe/alumni/showthread.php?t=19&page=2`.

The correct code for building the link should probably look like this:

```
echo '<a href="showthread.php?t='.$id.'&page='.($x + 1).'" class="label label-danger">'.$page.'</a>&nbsp;';
```

Or, while I'm at it, a bit cleaner imo would be something like this:

```
$requestedPage = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;

for($page = 1; $page <= $fetch["count(*)"] / $limit; $page++) {
    // active page does not need to be a link
    if($requestedPage == $page) {
        echo "<strong>$page</strong>";
        continue;
    }
    echo "<a href='showthread.php?t=$id&page=$page' class='label label-danger'>$page</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIMIT` you can limit the number of rows to display per page, by setting `limit` and `offset`.

```
$total = $dbcon->query("SELECT count(*) FROM comment") or die(mysqli_error());
$num_rows = $total->fetch_assoc()["count(*)"]; // get row count

$limit = 8;
$lastPage = round(($num_rows / $limit) - 1); // get last page
$current_page = isset($_GET['t']) ? $_GET['t'] : 0; // if not set the page is index.php
$offset = $current_page * $limit; // get offset by multiplying the current page number by limit

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment LIMIT $offset, $limit";
$result = $dbcon->query($sql); // get results using LIMIT

// display results here
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}

echo createNav($current_page, $lastPage); // creating pagination

function createNav($pageNumber, $lastPage)
{
    $listItems = '';
    while ($lastPage >= 1) {
        $pageNumber += 1;
        if ($pageNumber >= 1) {
            $listItems = createListItem($pageNumber, $lastPage) . $listItems;
        }
        $lastPage -= 1;
    }
    return $listItems;
}

function createListItem($pageNumber, $lastPage)
{
    if ($pageNumber <= $lastPage && $lastPage > 0) {
        return '<a href="showthread.php?t=' . $pageNumber . '?&page=' . ($pageNumber + 1) . '">' . $pageNumber . '</a><br>';
    }
}
```

[check this simple pagination](https://github.com/julekgwa/php_paginator)

Comment: no you cannot use $pageNumber as value for t. in `return '<a href="showthread.php?t=' . $pageNumber . '?&page=' . ($pageNumber + 1) . '">' . $pageNumber . '</a><br>';` because the value of t is the id of the current thread. anyway, this question is already answered by Pevara in the comment above.